# Swift Poststring don't get my Values

Tags: php, swift, request, geolocation, core-location

I want to have the Value of latitude and longitude in my poststring to send it to my php file, but it doesn't give values- I get this error code:

> responseString = Optional("")
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

My respsonsestring is empty
this is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol FeedmodelProtocol: class { func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) }

class Feedmodel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

weak var delegate: FeedmodelProtocol!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager() // create Location Manager object
var latitude : Double?
var longitude : Double?

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    // set the value of lat and long
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude

}

func downloadItems() {
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    // You will need to update your .plist file to request the authorization
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://example.com/stock_service4.php");
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "latiTude=\(String(describing: latitude))&longiTude=\(String(describing: longitude))"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in


        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return

        }


        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        self.parseJSON(data)

    }

    task.resume()

}

func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

    var jsonResult = NSArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray;
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)

    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let stocks = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {
        print(jsonResult)
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary


        let stock = Stockmodel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if  let Datum = jsonElement["Datum"] as? String,
            let Tankstelle = jsonElement["Tankstelle"] as? String,
            let Kraftstoff1 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff1"] as? String,
            let Preis1 = jsonElement["Preis1"] as? String,
            let Kraftstoff2 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff2"] as? String,
            let Preis2 = jsonElement["Preis2"] as? String,
            let Notiz = jsonElement["Notiz"] as? String,
            let longitude = jsonElement["longitude"] as? String,
            let latitude = jsonElement["latitude"] as? String



        {
            print (Datum)
            print(Tankstelle)
            print(Kraftstoff1)
            print(Preis1)
            print(Kraftstoff2)
            print(Preis2)
            print(Notiz)
            print(longitude)
            print(latitude)
            stock.Datum = Datum
            stock.Tankstelle = Tankstelle
            stock.Kraftstoff1 = Kraftstoff1
            stock.Preis1 = Preis1
            stock.Kraftstoff2 = Kraftstoff2
            stock.Preis2 = Preis2
            stock.Notiz = Notiz
            stock.longitude = longitude
            stock.latitude = latitude


        }

        stocks.add(stock)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

    })
}

}
```

This line don't send the values to my php:

```
  let postString = "latiTude=\(String(describing: latitude))&longiTude=\(String(describing: longitude))"
```

But if I set latitude and longitude manually in this line like:

```
let postString = "latiTude=28&longiTude=-99"
```

It works perfect.

What could be the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The `latitude` and `longitude` variables are set in the `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` but this fonction is call (every time when the location is update) after the function `downloadItems()`. So you should add `downloadItems()` in the location manager like this :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    // set the value of lat and long
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude

    downloadItems()
}
```

> Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012861/how-to-wait-for-variable-in-swift-before-executing-function-swift)